# Deadlocked in windows filter graph

Tags: filter, directshow, deadlock, mediacontroller

this is a hard to reproduce bug, but I finally managed to reproduce it. However, I do not have a clear understanding of what might have caused it.  I am currently trying to push myself through this bug and figure out the source of error.

Wondering if someone can give me some directions or hints.

---

My program is deadlocked in the stop function in Directshow Filter graph.

here is the call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!_ZwDeviceIoControlFile@40()  + 0x15 bytes 
ntdll.dll!_ZwDeviceIoControlFile@40()  + 0x15 bytes 
KernelBase.dll!_CreateEventExW@16()  + 0x6e bytes   
ksproxy.ax!SetState()  + 0x3e bytes 
ksproxy.ax!Inactive()  + 0x3d bytes
```

> ksproxy.ax!CKsOutputPin::Inactive()  + 0x1d bytes
>       ksproxy.ax!CKsProxy::Stop()  + 0x59 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::Stop()  + 0x123f3 bytes
>       **quartz.dll!CFGControl::CImplMediaControl::Stop()  + 0x12dba bytes**    <--- Called into direct show
>       *cam.dll!UVCCamera::Shutdown()  Line 140 + 0x1b bytes   C++
>       cam.dll!`anonymous namespace'::closeCamera(unsigned int hCamera)  Line 297  C++
>       cam.dll!`anonymous namespace'::CoreThreadFunc(void * data)  Line 916 + 0xb bytes    C++
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes
>       ntdll.dll!__*RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes
>
>       ntdll.dll!*_RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes*

Comment: maybe the bug is in avstream which is ksproxy

http://www.gdcl.co.uk/avstream.htm#flush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have solved this problem by using the method described at the end of the link below:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/53563921-6398-491c-999c-3bfaa2f218ca/

Now I am getting a different error!